# Camera Preview is stretched and skewed

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

How to solve the streching of image in my camera preview?

**Camera Preview Class**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 
private SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
private Camera mCamera;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG,
                    "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG,
                    "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        // method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // mCamera.release();

    }
}
```

Comment: Note the use of AspectFrameLayout in Grafika, e.g. "continuous capture" (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java). FWIW, while your image is being stretched, I would be surprised it were being skewed, as both source and destination are rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your CameraView's aspect ratio is not match with the aspect ratio of camera preview size.
You should caculate your CameraView's aspect ratio and use this aspect ratio to find best size for `Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize()` method.
Try this

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters parameters, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    double ratio = width / height;
    double w = 0, h = 0;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        w = size.width;
        h = size.height;
        if (w / h == ratio) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (w > result.width) {
                    result = size;
                }
            } else {
                result = size;
            }
        }

    }
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: where to call this method? and how to check whats the size of my preview?

Comment: First, you need to call this method before start preview. You can search 'how to set my camera preview size' to see the steps. Second, size of your preview is size of SurfaceView which you show on screen. Finally, fadden's suggestion is another way.